# layout going from top to bottom of screen

Tags: java, android

I have a screen where I have an action bar, then a title to a book and the chapter itself. Problem is,the chapter goes from top to bottom and the title is cutoff. The chapter text also overlaps appbar on top and bottom navigation view on bottom. Please help

content_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_home_bottom_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if you can consider using another layout rather than Constaintlayout then RelativeLayout will be good for such layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this as activity_home layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liner_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

leave the content_home layout as it is.